# Why does cv2.HoughCirles minRadius and maxRadius seem to require "padding" around radius to work?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I've been experimenting with OpenCV to detect circular stamps on documents using `cv2.HoughCircles`. Some of these stamps are faded and partial, so I've had to increase dp, which ends up finding **lots** of circles. Thankfully, the stamps fall within a narrow range of radii, so I was hoping to use minRadius and maxRadius to filter out most/all of the false positives. As I attempted to do this, I discovered that I was needing to add padding to the acceptable range. The amount of padding required seems to vary, sometimes quite a bit.

When I discovered this the stamps were `radius=35` in the low resolution version of the scanned documents. However, I found that I had to set `minRadius=25` and `maxRadius=75` for it to be detected.

I set up a [jupyter notebook on Google Collaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mx7wlljMDCBE4A27R5t0sQE-v80DXfF8) to illustrate this, creating a 250x250 white image with a `radius=100` gray circle centered in it. I still had to "pad" the range to have it detected, but not nearly as much as in my real-world example. Furthermore, I found that changing the dp value of the HOUGHGRADIENT changed the amount of padding needed. I also found that changing the padding changed the detected radius!

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.71, 10, minRadius=95, maxRadius=105)
```

In the Colab example, I only needed to pad by about +/- 5%, which would be fine, but with the actual documents I was needing to pad by factors of 2 or more, which causes too many false positives.

It occurs to me as I write this question that I could loop through the results and throw out circles too small or large, which would solve my immediate problem, but not help me understand what's happening. So, what am I missing?

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.71, 10, minRadius=95, maxRadius=105)
```

I expect that if the method finds a circle with radius 100 that setting `minRadius=maxRadius=100` would still allow it to be detected, but instead I am having to set a wider range. Furthermore, changing the range can change the detected radius, which I would not expect.

Comment: Do you know the basics of the Hough transform and how it works, in theory?

Comment: I do not, but am hoping to look into it soon.

Comment: @pr3sidentspence Check out this blog post about the Hough transform: https://www.learnopencv.com/hough-transform-with-opencv-c-python/.

Comment: Okay, I get now that the min/max settings aren't filters but possible circles it iterates through. Although, that still doesn't make me understand why they need so much padding in my real-world images. I found this to be the best explanation I've found so far of the transform: http://aishack.in/tutorials/circle-hough-transform/